# get input values from other input

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

im having a little problem, i have a form, with three fields, my problem is this one:
on the 2 and 3 input i get via javascript values for countries and cities, what i want to do is to make the city input throw the values from the country i have selected in the country input, heres the javascript

```
     <script>
 var availableTags = [
 <?php 

 $sql = "select * from citys ";
 $rsd = mysql_query($sql);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
{
    $pid=$row['cid'];
    $city=$row['city'];
    $state=$row['state'];
 ?>
    "<?php echo $city; ?>,<?php echo $state; ?>",
    <?php } ?>

 ];
 $( "#inputsearch21" ).autocomplete({
 source: function( request, response ) {
 var matches = $.map( availableTags, function(tag) {
 if ( tag.toUpperCase().indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) === 0 ) {
    return tag;
  }
});
response(matches);
}
 });
</script>
```

and the country script is the same, changing the php for country database.
i know i have to get the country id from the first form and in the second query i should be "select * from citys where countryid="$countryid"

any idea how to do this?

Comment: Ouch.  Format the code, please.  It's hard to look at....

Comment: There's a syntax error at the second line from the end, It closes the function of `source` but it only has `}` instead of `})`

Comment: i edited there, more clearly

Comment: Tips: 
- use json_encode() when transforming php arrays into javascript arrays.
- you're not using $pid, so why are you setting it? Why are you selecting it, even? Replace the * in the select statement with just city, state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best thing to do is to work with an cobmination ajax and json. Then It should be something like this.

**getCities.php**

```
<?php
  /* your connection ofc. */
  $con = database_connection();

  /* example unsecure please use PDO */
  $sql = "SELECT ID, Name FROM City WHERE Country = '" . $_GET['country'] . "'";
  $rsd = mysql_query($sql); 
  $res = mysql_fetch_array($rsd);

  /* Return output in json format */
  echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "getCities.php",
  data: { country: "Germany" }
}).done(function( output ) {
  /* Example for select inputs */
  var cities = eval('(' + output + ')');
  var length = cities.length;

  for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    var newOption = $('<option/>');
    newOption.attr('text', cities[i].Text);
    newOption.attr('value', cities[i].Value);
    $('#ID-OF-SELECTBOX').append(newOption);
  }
});
```

Comment: In this example I used an select box, but you can also use your auto complete script there.